# page_url vs navigate_to in page-object gem + Jruby

Tags: jruby, page-object-gem

I am trying to use jruby + page-object gem + Cucumber for a proof of concept. I used the following statement.

`app_url = 'https:\\google.com'

       page_url(app_url)`

I get a

> NoMethodError: undefined method `page_url' for #

However,

> navigate_to(app_url)

works fine. page_url works fine in Ruby.

Is this the way this works in jRuby?  Though navigate_to works, is this any different? 
Thank you for your help!

Comment: It seems strange that you are comparing `page_url` with `navigate_to` since their usage is very different. Are you sure you are using them in the same context for Ruby vs JRuby?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`page_url` is a class method provided by including the `PageObject module`. It sets the url for the page so you can use the `visit_page` factory in your test:

```
object MyPage
  include PageObject
  page_url "http://example.com/"
end
```

In a test somewhere:

```
visit_page MyPage do |page|
  page.some_object_element.do_something
end
```

`navigate_to` is browser functionality exposed directly in your test via some `World` magic.